# Multiple plots in a for loop with Sweave

Tags: r, sweave

My chunk in Sweave:

```
<<fig=TRUE,echo=FALSE>>=
for(i in 1:10) {
  plot(rep(i,10))
  dev.new()
}
@
```

In the resulting pdf I get only one plot (from the first iteration). I would like to have all of the 10 plots printed. What am I doing wrong? I tried replacing `dev.new()` with `frame()` and `plot.new()` but nothing happened.

Comment: try `fig.keep = 'all'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @rawr suggests the easiest solution is to *switch to `knitr`* (there's really no reason at all not to!) and put `fig.keep="all"` in your code chunk options (if you switch to `knitr` you don't need `fig=TRUE` any more ... including figures works automatically, `fig.keep="none"` is the analogue of `fig=FALSE`)

Alternatively, if you want to stick with vanilla Sweave, check the [Sweave manual](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/Sweave-manual.pdf) p. 17:

> **A.9 Creating several figures from one figure chunk does not work**
>
> Consider that you want to create several graphs in a loop similar to

```
<<fig=TRUE>>
for (i in 1:4) plot(rnorm(100)+i)
@
```

> This will currently not work, because Sweave allows only one graph per figure chunk. The simple reason is that Sweave opens a postscript device before executing the code and closes it
>   afterwards. If you need to plot in a loop, you have to program it along the lines of

```
<<results=tex,echo=FALSE>>=
for(i in 1:4){
file=paste("myfile", i, ".eps", sep="")
postscript(file=file, paper="special", width=6, height=6)
plot(rnorm(100)+i)
dev.off()
cat("\\includegraphics{", file, "}\n\n", sep="")
}
@
```

Comment: After the first use I must admit - knitr and markdown are awesome.